# Deploying Rails with subdomains using capistrano to an nginx/unicorn setup -- how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, subdomain, unicorn

I've been following Ryan B's VPS deployment railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps

nginx.conf file he suggest using doesn't work with subdomains.  This is what he shows:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.blog.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/<app name>/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Does anyone know how to set things up to support subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out (at least with linode.com), that handeling wildcard subdomains is pretty straight forward.  You just need to add a `*` host to the A record.

Also, in nginix, what I did was replaced:

```
# server_name example.com;
```

with:

```
server_name localhost;
```

I'm not sure that's even needed.

My actual issue had nothing to do with either the host or nginx.  My situation was that I was using a random hashed URL as a security token during registration (so a user can't hijack an existing subdomain), but the type of hash I was using had issues so I needed to modify it.

I wasn't seeing any errors, I was just being redirected back to the signup page -- as is the correct behavior when the hashed URL has problems / doesn't match.

Anyway, once I fixed that, the whole subdomain thing was a non-issue.

Hope this helps anyone else who uses hashed URLs, subdomains, and is generally new to deployment.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can uncomment line:

`# server_name example.com;`

replace example.com with your domain and add:

`server_name example.com *.example.com;`
or

`server_name example.com blog.example.com;`

Now all requests to domain and subdomains will go to the rails